# Google Script vs Formula - MATCHing Records

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

At the moment I have a worksheet with Prior Students Names and ID#.  There are at the moment about 3000 records.

In a second worksheet I have new names listed (which are entered via a form).

At the moment I am using the following to check if there is a prior record:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Students!A:A,MATCH(K2, Students!B:B; 0)), "NEW STUDENT")
```

But the spreadsheet is getting quite slow.

Would a google script be better?  And if so how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a different formula.  For example, in [this example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvhOXv5OGFq6dGtJY1R6VzRRR2V5SVF5UXZuSzBfNHc#gid=1) I have added 10,000 rows of fake data, in Sheet1.   I have joined the first name column with the second name column in  a cell, in Sheet2!A1, as below:

```
=arrayformula(join(";", Sheet1!B:B & " " & Sheet1!C:C))
```

Then I can perform a text search for a new name into this long string.  Eg the following:

```
=find("Peter Piper"&";", Sheet2!A1)
```

It is fast.

Comment: Cool - and if only student IDs are interesting, the string would be shorter. The [limitations](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603) mention that there _are_ overall spreadsheet size limits, but not what they are... I wonder how big this one cell could get? (Although this solution is already beyond the scale mentioned initially.)

Comment: I am going to start with the array and then slowly work on the scriptdb as I have limited prog skills.

Answer (score 1):

"Better"? That's just too subjective. Let's only talk performance.

You should be able to write a script that will perform these specific look-ups much faster than your current spreadsheets. The dominant factor is the number of calculations being performed;

- Spreadsheet formulas are recalculated every time there is a change in the sheet. So your "new student" checks on students that you already have in the second worksheet are wasting time.
- A form submission trigger function would ideally do the lookup in response to a form, and only for the new student data.
- A script could use [`ScriptDB`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb) to store all the Prior student names & ids, thereby eliminating the need to read the Prior student spreadsheet over and over, and providing fast lookups.

  ```
  ...
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  var result = db.query({id: newId});
  if (!result.hasNext()) {
    event.range.offset(0,statusColumn).setValue("NEW STUDENT");
  }
  ```

Counter-points do exist, here's just a couple.

- You need to write javascript code, rather than spreadsheet functions. It's a different skill set.
- If you're using ScriptDb for performance, you need to include some maintenance capability; at the very least, you need to load the database the first time.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will work
=dget(Students!A:B,Students!$A$1,{Students!$B$1;$K$2})
given k2 is the search text.

if you get #na!, you get new student. if #num! then you have multiple match. dget is a database function. Thus it can handle large data quite well. however it is not as flexible but efficient function.